# PasswordHash not found in namespace

Tags: password

I'm very new to WordPress development, coming from a pure OO background I'm familiarising myself with object-orientation in PHP / WordPress.

I have a class at entities\Member, that get's loaded via an autoloader implementation. This stuff I'm quite comfortable with, and up until now, I've not really used WordPress specific functions in my code.

For members, I want to use the built in password hasher function that lives in the pluggable.php file, but for some reason the autoloader tries to 'lookup' the PasswordHash function as a class, which it should not be doing?

I've browsed around for possible solutions to this, but it seems to be a limitation in WordPress and it's handling of object-orientation in PHP 5+?

How can an 'fool' the autoloader to ignore WordPress functions, if at all possible?

I have tried adding the require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/pluggable.php'); in the Members class, even in the functions.php class, just above the autoloader include. No go.

Comment: Actually `PasswordHash` [**is** a class](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/class-phpass.php#L36). In global namespace, of course. Have you tried `\PasswordHash`? The function you're talking about I think is [`wp_hash_password`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password)

Comment: @G.M. i did, however, you might've just pointed out a flaw in my autoloader :$. thank you

Comment: try `require_once (ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/class-phpass.php');` it works for me.

Comment: you may use use `global $wp_hasher;`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Vee

> try require_once (ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/class-phpass.php'); it works for me.

It did worked for me too.

Came on this thread about a month ago and found no solution so I had to restore from a backup. The problem came back and I'm very happy of your contribution.